# Inserting SCOPE_IDENTITY() into a junction table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following little script:

```
create table #test
(testId int identity
,testColumn varchar(50)
)
go
create table #testJunction
(testId int
,otherId int
)


 insert into #test
    select 'test data'
    insert into #testJunction(testId,otherId)
    select SCOPE_IDENTITY(),(select top 10 OtherId from OtherTable)
--The second query here signifies some business logic to resolve a many-to-many 
--fails
```

This, however, will work:

```
insert into #test
select 'test data'
insert into #testJunction(otherId,testId)
select top 10 OtherId ,(select SCOPE_IDENTITY())
from OtherTable
--insert order of columns is switched in #testJunction
--SCOPE_IDENTITY() repeated for each OtherId
```

The second solution works and all is well.  I know it doesn't matter, but for continuity's sake I like having the insert done in the order in which the columns are present in the database table.  How can I acheieve that?  The following attempt gives a `subquery returned more than 1 value` error

```
insert into #test
select 'test data'
insert into #testJunction(otherId,testId)
values ((select SCOPE_IDENTITY()),(select top 10 drugId from Drugs))
```

EDIT:
On a webpage a new row is entered into a table with a structure like

```
    QuizId,StudentId,DateTaken
(QuizId is an identity column)
```

I have another table with Quiz Questions like

```
QuestionId,Question,CorrectAnswer
```

Any number of quizzes can have any number of questions, so in this example `testJunction`
resolves that many to many.  Ergo, I need the SCOPE_IDENTITY repeated for however many questions are on the quiz.

Comment: Unsure what your question is. Can you provide example data? The second one (which you say works) inserts the same `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for all ten rows. Is that the intention? If so why do you care what the insert order is?

Comment: Yes, so in this example there's a many-to-many relationship between a Quiz object and QuizQuestions.  So Quiz number 1 can have many QuizQuestions.  The many-to-many resolves quizzes and questions.

Comment: @MartinSmith I care what the insert order is only because it feels like cheating because I don't know how to do it a different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version that fails

```
insert into #testJunction(testId,otherId)
select SCOPE_IDENTITY(),(select top 10 OtherId from OtherTable)
```

will insert one row with `scope_identity()` in the first column and a set of 10 values in the second column. A column can not have sets so that one fails.

The one that works

```
insert into #testJunction(otherId,testId)
select top 10 OtherId ,(select SCOPE_IDENTITY())
from OtherTable
```

will insert 10 rows from `OtherTable` with `OtherId` in the first column and the scalar value of `scope_identity()` in the second column.

If you need to switch places of the columns it would look like this instead.

```
insert into #testJunction(testId,otherId)
select top 10 SCOPE_IDENTITY(), OtherId
from OtherTable
```

Comment: that's it.  This wasn't a very practical question because I had a solution that worked, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking some silly, mundane detail of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You need the output clause. Look it up in BOL.

Comment: I've yet to use that, guess it's time to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
 Declare @Var int
 insert into #test
 select 'test data'
 select @var=scope_identity()
 insert into #testJunction(otherId,testId)
 select top 10 @var,drugId from Drugs
```